Expected value of mean reverting spot price - triple numerical integral
I have been reading this paper: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=7d38b03cfc62a15bdfd755c793d4e70a821725cc and having trouble trying to implement the expected value of the term
$$f(T) = aLe^{-aT+\sigma W(T)-\frac{\sigma^2T}{2}}\int_0^Te^{as-\sigma W(s) +\frac{\sigma^2s}{2}}ds.$$
Changing the variables I can write the term in the following form
$$f(T_0)=\frac{4L}{\sigma^2}e^{-2(B^{(v)}_{T_0})}A^{(v)}_{T_0}.$$
Using theorem 4.3.-1 in the paper I can write the expectation as
$$E[f(T_0)]=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{4aL}{\sigma^2\xi^2y}\xi^\mu e^{-\frac{1}{2}y(1+\xi^2)}\theta(\xi y, T_0)d\xi dy,$$
where
$$\theta(r, t)=\frac{r}{\sqrt{2\pi^3t}}e^{\frac{\pi^2}{2t}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2T_0}-r\cosh(z)}\sinh(z)\sin(\frac{\pi z}{T_0})dz.$$
I have implemented the $\theta$ function by using the Gaver-Stehfest Laplace inversion (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-09114-3_19 chapter "A Note on the Numerical Evaluation of the Hartman–Watson Density and Distribution Function" section 4 and match the graph shown in the book so that part is okay, however, the reamining integral is where I struggle and using scipy.integrate.dblquad, doesn't work, i.e., it either takes a long time or it results in nan, probably due to the theta function.
I have also tried to implement the double integrals myself using the available quadrature methods, but I am unable to get the integral in the correct form to use them - the term $e^{-u}$ is fine as there is a quadrature method for this but can't find an appropiate one for the remainding integral; possibly due to the cross term $uy^2$ (unless I can then change variables using $u_i$ term from the first quadrature as a constant to get it into a form with $e^{-x^2}$ and use quadrature again?). If I first evaluate the $u$ integral with quadrature then use scipy.integrate.quad on the remaining integral, it takes forever and doesn't come back with an answer (or I haven't waited long enough).
I have also tried to do it using monte carlo methods but for the same reason above, I can't find the appropiate distribution to evaluate the remaining integral $\xi$ integral.
I have also tried to do it using equation (17) in the paper, but when comparing it to the mean (see the below paragraph) the answer varies with changing $\sigma$ and diverges away from the analytical answer so something must be going on with the two Brownian motions, one in the martingale term and another in the integral - I assumed you can integrate using the Brownian motion distribution (i.e., normal distribution), one with variance $T$ and the other with variance $s$ (inside the definite integral), but this just wasn't working as mentioned in the start of the paragraph...
To test my implementation I have compared it to
$$E\left[ae^{\sigma W(T)-\frac{\sigma^2T}{2}}\int_0^Te^{as-\sigma W(s) +\frac{\sigma^2s}{2}}ds\right]=e^{aT}-1.$$
which is a result obtained in the paper.
Any feedback/suggestions would be appreciated and any code implementations would be appreciated - see one of my efforts below.
from scipy.special import iv
from scipy.special import comb
def theta(r, x):
        n = 10
        aa = np.log(2.0)/x
        def a(k):
            floor = np.floor((k+1)/2.0)
            min_bound = np.minimum(k, n)
            sum_a = 0
            for j in range(int(np.floor((k+1)/2.0)), int(np.minimum(k, n))+1):
                sum_a += np.power(j, n+1)*comb(n, j)*comb(2.0*j, j)*comb(j, k-j)
            return np.power(-1.0, k+n)/math.factorial(n)*sum_a
        sum_bess = 0
        for k in range(1, int(2*n)+1):
            sum_bess += a(k)*iv(np.sqrt(2.0*k*np.log(2.0)/x), r)
        return aa*sum_bess

def eta_mean(a, T, sigma):
   from scipy import integrate as inte
   mu = 2.0*a/(sigma*sigma)+1.0
   T0 = sigma*sigma*T/4.0
   def f1(y, v):
      return np.power(v, -1.0)*np.power(y, mu-2.0)*np.exp(-0.5*v*(1.0+y*y))*new_theta(y*v, T0)
   return inte.dblquad(f1, 0.0, np.inf, 0.0, np.inf)[0]


A possible reason those scipy quadratures give nan might be due to the integration around \zeta=0 or y=0 since the evaluation of theta still has some errors. If you can isolate that part (use a local Taylor expansion for that small region), then the rest might be integrated by the scipy routine.
